# Filling preallocated `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to append a lot (1 440 000 000) of rows to a `pandas.DataFrame`.

I know the number of rows in advance, so I can preallocate it, then fill it with data in a C-like manner.

So far the best idea I have is pretty ugly:

```
>>> N = 1000000
>>> sham = [-1] * (N * len(THRESHOLDS) * len(OBJECTS)) # 1440000000
>>> DATA = pd.DataFrame({'threshold': pd.Categorical(sham, categories=THRESHOLDS, ordered=True),
...                      'expected': pd.Series(sham, dtype=np.float16),
...                      'iteration': pd.Series(sham, dtype=np.int32),
...                      'analyser': pd.Categorical(sham, categories=ANALYSERS),
...                      'object': pd.Categorical(sham, categories=OBJECTS),
...                     },
...                     columns=['threshold', 'expected', 'iteration', 'analyser', 'object'])
>>> ptr = 0
>>> for t in THRESHOLDS:
...     for o in OBJECTS:
...         for a in ANALYSERS:
...             for i in range(N):
...                 DATA.iloc[ptr] = t, expectedMonteCarlo(o, a, t), i, a, o
...                 ptr += 1
```

The question is, **how can I make my code cleaner?** I mean especially:

- preallocate `DATA` without inflating it with `sham` list,
- append rows to preallocated `DATA` without use of index?

The main problem is memory efficiency. Otherwise I would go for appending records to `list` object, and then converting it to `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: Are you writing on a file? If so, it's better to write rows one by one on a text file, and then importing the file into pandas (you can then take care of memory problems later in the importing phase).

Comment: @FabioLamanna it may work for me. Is there a way to store rows in binary format loadable to `DataFrame`, or do I need to stick to CSV?

Comment: There are several formats you can load a `DataFrame` from, see [the IO documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id12).

Comment: @DavidZ yes, but which of them are both binary and row-by-row appendable? Also, the list is focused on saving, not loading `DataFrames` and is missing loading options for some formats - see comments in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494359/4879688

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(index=range(<num_expected>),  
             columns=['threshold', 'expected', 'iteration', 'analyser', 'object'],
             dtype=[('expected', numpy.float16), ('iteration', numpy.int32)],
            ) ` can get you the DataFrame. The only thing I doin't know 100% is how to handle the `categorical` data

Comment: you can already fill all values into the DataFrame, except the `expectedMonteCarlo(o, a, t)`, but you can fill that in by looping over the dataframe with `DataFrame.apply()` or use `[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)` for `t`, `o`, `i` and `a`, and `enumerate` for `ptr`