# How to store `pandas.DataFrame` in a PANDAS-LOADABLE binary format other than `pickle`

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with saving `pandas.DataFrame` (1 440 000 000 rows).

From what I can see in the API, the only available options to store (and then load) the array are either CSV or pickle.

Saving in pickle format ends with a mysterious exception (`SystemError: error return without exception set`), while saving in CSV is a waste of space even if it is compressed (2-byte-long `np.float16` is much more efficient than ASCII-encoded value).

How can I store my dataframe in a loadable, memory-efficient (including disk space) format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your data frame is too big. Pickle has some limits. You are much better off either saving in a database or using *to_hdf* (or lots of other IO routines, *to_msgpack* might works as well).

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html

Comment: I was considering use of `.to_hdf()`, but I can find no function to load the data back to a `DataFrame`. And that possibility is for me vital, since I need to analyse the data.

Comment: what about read_hdf? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html

Comment: Oh, it seems to be what I need. Pandas' API is not very intuitive - I was expecting `pandas.DataFrame.from_hdf()` method -_-.

Comment: @abukaj I think you can select my answer as the final answer, thanks

Comment: in pandas 20.0 the `feather` storage was introduced. This looks promising too

Comment: @Paddy I am going to - as soon as my code finishes its store/reading cycle :)